# How do I get the correct path that maximize the path sum for a given binary tree?

Tags: python

I'm trying to write some kind of a variant of the solution to [Leetcode 124 Binary Tree Maximum Path Sum](https://leetcode.com/problems/binary-tree-maximum-path-sum/):

> A **path** in a binary tree is a sequence of nodes where each pair of adjacent nodes in the sequence has an edge connecting them. A node can only appear in the sequence **at most once**. Note that the path does not need to pass through the root.
>
> The **path sum** of a path is the sum of the node's values in the path.
>
> Given the `root` of a binary tree, return *the maximum **path sum** of any **non-empty** path.*

By variant, I mean that in addition to giving the maximum path sum, the method also produces the full path.

The definition for a binary tree node is as on Leetcode, with an extra method:

```
class TreeNode:
  def __init__(self, val=0, left=None, right=None):
    self.val = val
    self.left = left
    self.right = right

  def to_binary_tree(items):
    """Generate a BT from a given list"""
    n = len(items)
    if n == 0:
      return None

    def inner(index: int = 0):
      """Closure function using recursion bo build tree"""
      if n <= index or items[index] is None:
        return None

      node = TreeNode(items[index])
      node.left = inner(2 * index + 1)
      node.right = inner(2 * index + 2)
      return node

    return inner()
```

In addition to the constructor, I added the `to_binary_tree` method which generates a BT from a given list.

Here is the solution part.

```
class Solution:
  def maxPathSum(self, root: TreeNode) -> int:
    def traversal(root):
      if root is None:
        return 0
      left = max(0, traversal(root.left))
      right = max(0, traversal(root.right))
      layerSum = left + right + root.val
      if(layerSum>self.res):
        self.res = layerSum
        self.path = [left, root.val, right]
      return max(left, right, 0) + root.val

    self.res = float("-inf")
    self.path = []
    traversal(root)
    return self.res, self.path
```

In addition to giving the maximum path sum, it also returns the corresponding path.

## case_1

For example, given list [-10, 9, 20, None, None, 15, 7]

```
root = TreeNode.to_binary_tree([-10, 9, 20, None, None, 15, 7])
testSolution = Solution()
print(testSolution.maxPathSum(root))
```

the above code produces

```
(42, [15, 20, 7])
```

which is as expected.

## case_2

However, given another list `[10, -2, 7, 8, -4, None, None]`,

```
              10
           /      \
         -2        7
       /   \     
      8     -4
```

the method `maxPathSum` returns

```
(23, [6, 10, 7])
```

which is close to but not exactly as expected. The expectation is

```
(23, [8, -2, 10, 7])
```

How do I get that?

## case_3

For list `[-15, 5, 6, -8, 1, 3, 9, 2, 6, None, None, None, None, None, 0, None, None, None, None, 4, -1, None, None, 10, None]`

corresponding to the follow BT

```
       -15
       / \
      /   \
     /     \
    5       6
   / \     / \
  -8  1   3   9
 / \           \
2   6           0
               / \
              4  -1
                 /
                10
```

the method `maxPathSum` returns

```
(18, [3, 6, 9])
```

where neither the sum nor the path is as expected. The expectation is

```
(27, [3, 6, 9, 0 – 1, 10])
```

What am I missing?

Comment: What do you mean "_some kind of a variant_"? What is your question, exactly?

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar The question is how do I get the full path like `[8, -2, 10, 7]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this assignment:

```
self.path = [left, root.val, right]
```

it is evident that the length of the path is *always* 3. `left` and `right` are sums, so only when those sums happen to come from a single node, will this represent the path you want to get. But if the sum is derived from multiple nodes, you need to know which nodes they were.

To achieve that, you should let `traverse` also return the path together with the found sum.

Here is the adapted code for `traverse`:

```
        def traversal(root):
            if root is None:
                return 0, []
            
            left, left_path = max((0, []), traversal(root.left))
            right, right_path = max((0, []), traversal(root.right))
            layer_sum = left + right + root.val
            if layer_sum > self.res:
                self.res = layer_sum
                self.path = left_path + [root.val] + right_path[::-1]
            if left > right:
                return left + root.val, left_path + [root.val]
            else:
                return right + root.val, right_path + [root.val]
```

### The list format

Your code to build a tree from a list will only produce the same tree as LeetCode would, when it has all its leaves in the bottom two levels of the tree. In other cases, the LeetCode encoding into a list will not include some of the `None` values your code expects to be there. Take for example this tree:

```
         1 
          \  
           3
          / \
         2   4
```

LeetCode would represent that tree as `[1, None, 3, 2, 4]`, not as `[1, None, 3, None, None, 2, 4]`. In other words, if a node has no child, its `None` grandchildren -- that would have been children of that `None` child -- are not taking slots in the list representation.

If you want to support the list input as LeetCode would give it, then use the following method:

```
def to_binary_tree(items):
    if not items:
        return None

    it = iter(items)
    root = TreeNode(next(it))
    q = [root]
    for node in q:
        val = next(it, None)
        if val is not None:
            node.left = TreeNode(val)
            q.append(node.left)
        val = next(it, None)
        if val is not None:
            node.right = TreeNode(val)
            q.append(node.right)
    return root
```

Comment: Thank you so much! The helpful answer does solve case_2 though, the bug found in case_3 is still in there.

Comment: The case 3 doesn't build the tree you depict, because of what I posted in the second half of my answer, and so it is normal you don't get the expected answer, since you don't feed it the tree you think you do. More specifically, the node with value 0 sits at index 14, and your code assumes its children (if any) are at indices 29 and 30, which obviously is not where they are in that list.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out another bug. my code gives (4, [1, 3]) for `[1, None, 3, 2, 4]` but the expectation is (9, [2, 3, 4]), is my understanding correct?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. Again, this is because your code does not build the tree that you expect. For that tree, your code would build it correctly if you provided those extra `None` values, like so: `[1, None, 3, None, None, 2, 4]`. But this is not the LeetCode way of encoding that tree in a list.

Comment: I see the problem, `to_binary_tree` is losing the children of `3` for `[1, None, 3, 2, 4]`

Comment: Added code to my answer that expects a list that is constructed like LeetCode would do it.

Comment: quite close to perfect. just one tiny bug for case_3, the expected order of the node is `[3, 6, 9, 0 – 1, 10]` or in reversed order whereas the code gives `[3, 6, 10, -1, 0, 9]`. Anyway, you're great, I already marked and thumbed up the answer. Thank you so much!

Comment: For that you can reverse the `right_path` when building `self.path`. Updated.